# Unable to change keyboard input source when the selected source is not english

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, language-support

I have recently upgraded my ubuntu from 18 to 20.04 LTS.

So I have two main input sources of language, Egnlish and Arabic.

Firstly, I can change the input source from the tray no problem with that.

But I can use the keyboard shortcut `super+space` to change the source **only if the current selected is English!** 
So suppose the current selected language is English, then I want to write something in Arabic, I use the keyboard shortcut `super+space` to change to Arabic. Then I want to change to English again [this when the keyboard shortcut doesn't work], I can only change from the tray bar.

Comment: This is probably related to [bug #1871913](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1871913). You may want to upgrade the `mutter` package from focal-proposed (or wait a few days until the fix reaches focal-updates).

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I upgraded the mutter package but the problem still persist.

Comment: Maybe you need to upgrade `libmutter-6-0` and `gir1.2-mutter-6` too. All packages with "mutter" in their names should be version `3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1`. (And then you need to relogin.)

Comment: I did update mutter common initially in order to install mutter...Anyway, now I am using unity instead of gnome where everything is working fine, also I got my left mouse button working again.